# Avoid trottling when Electron App is minimised or system is screen-locked

Tags: node.js, electron, nodes, throttling

I am facing throttling issues when running the electron app is minimized and system is screen-locked. The application used node-ffi-napi to get messages from a DLL continuously. When the app  window is minimized the application's performance depreciates.

What I have tried so far:

- powerSaveBlocker.start('prevent-app-suspension')
- powerSaveBlocker.start('prevent-display-sleep')
- set the pageVisibility: true and backgroundThrottling: false for the main window as well as browser windows.
- Globally set app.commandLine.appendSwitch(disable-renderer-backgrounding)

Any suggestions to keep the app active and improve the performance.

Comment: I have the same issue as you. Keep your eyes on this thread in case the developers update anything.

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9567